# How to auto fill value of a cell in slick grid on change of another cell value

Tags: jquery, html, excel, autocomplete, slickgrid

OnchangeCell event of slick grid is not getting call first time when someone first time enters value in the cell, it is calling when someone change the value of cell.

My requirement is to auto fill the another cell on change(also first time user enters the value in it) a cell. Please help... Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, onCellChange event does not fire first time, you have to use onAddNewRow event to cover this. So basically the work around is you have to use both the events.

Hope this will solve your problem.